# Type Guard function with multiple dynamic types

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a type guard function which checks for multiple types.
It should be a mix of typeof operator and instanceof operator.

I started with the following implementation:

```
function typeof(obj: any, type: "string"): obj is string;
function typeof(obj: any, type: "number"): obj is number;
```

And I am using it the following way:

```
function do(value: any) {

  let str: string = "";
  let num: number = 0;

  if(typeof(value, "string")){
      str = value;
  }
  if(typeof(value, "number")){
      num = value;
  }
}
```

The function should also check against objects e.g. Date:

```
let date: Date = null;
if(typeof(value, Date)){
    date = value;
}
```

I tried:

```
function typeof<K>(obj: any, type: K): obj is K;
```

But Typescript only show DateContructor if type is Date.

My final goal is a function which can check multiple types:

```
function typeof(obj, ...types:[]): ???

let date: Date = new Date();
//if(typeof value === "number" || value instanceof Date)
if(typeof(value, "number", Date)){
  date = date + value;
}
```

How should the typeOf function should be defined?

Comment: The code was not correct because it was checking for the type of the object using the typeof operator, but for the object type, it was using the .toString() method, which is not correct. To properly check for an object type, the instanceof operator must be used.

Comment: Your signature says `type: K` but you always pass `string`s there (`"number"`, ...) thus `K` is always inferred as `string`. At least change it to `function typeof<K>(obj: any, type: string): obj is K;` so that you call it `if (typeOf<number>(value, "number"))`. Not that I get what you're up to, just fixing your typing issue.

Comment: Sorry, I did not really show my declaration. I used overloading. I've declared: 

    `function typeof(obj: any, type: "string"): obj is string;
    function typeof(obj: any, type: "number"): obj is number;
    function typeof<K>(obj: any, type: K): obj is K;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the strings to work, we need a predefined map of strings to their respective types first:

```
type TypeofMap = {
    string: string;
    number: number;
    boolean: boolean;
    symbol: symbol;
    undefined: undefined;
    object: object;
    function: (...args: any[]) => any;
    bigint: bigint;
};
```

Then we can lookup the correct type later:

```
type ToType<T> =
    T extends keyof TypeofMap
        ? TypeofMap[T]
        : T extends new (...args: any[]) => infer R
            ? R
            : T;
```

I've also made it so that if `T` is a constructor, then the type should be an instance of `T`. Otherwise, I don't know anything else, so I will use `T` itself as the type.

Here's the signature for `typeOf` (note the capitalization on O, you cannot name functions "typeof"):

```
declare function typeOf<T extends keyof TypeofMap | {} | null | undefined>(value: any, type: T): value is ToType<T>;
```

The generic constraint looks weird because I wanted the function to autocomplete keys in `TypeofMap` if you try to pass a string for the type, but it should still allow any type. Since `{} | null | undefined` represents any possible value, but is different from `keyof TypeofMap`, I still get autocomplete and the union is not reduced to only `{} | null | undefined`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/weB7eN)

Comment: Thank you, it works quiet well, but I cannot understand why. I think my problem is to understand the type ToType

Comment: Is there also a way to check multiple? typeOf(value, "number", Date)

Comment: @NicoRichter Yea it would look something like this: https://tsplay.dev/WG4Ekw

Comment: Thanks again. This is confusing me more and more.